# iOS - compilation dependency

Tags: ios, c, compilation, dependencies

Supposed I have a class declared as below:

```
// ClassB.h
#import "ClassA"

@class ClassC;
@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassC *obj;
@end
```

The implementation file:

```
// ClassB.m
#import "ClassC.h"
#import "ClassD.h"
#import "ClassB.h"
...
```

The parent header file:

```
// ClassA.h
#import "ClassE.h"
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@end
```

Then modifications to which files would result in a recompilation for ClassB?
(ClassA.h? ClassA.m? ClassC.h? ClassC.m? ClassD.h? ClassD.m? ClassE.h? ClassE.m?)

Comment: Are you sure you do not have "#import "ClassB.h" in ClassB.m ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to any the listed header files will cause ClassB to be recompiled.

I assume your ClassB.m file imports ClassB.h. With that and the C, D header imports; the A import in the B header; and the fact that the A header imports E header.

The only .m file that will cause a recompile of ClassB is ClassB.m.

Just follow the chain of which files are accessible from ClassB.m. Remember that imports suck in code from other files.

Comment: What if in ClassA.h, I used @class ClassE instead of importing. The #import "ClassE.h" is placed in ClassA.m and not ClassB.m. Would a modification in ClassE.h result in a recompile of ClassB as well?

Comment: In that case, a modification to ClassE.h would not cause ClassB to be recompiled.

Comment: The "@class" directive tells the compiler, for the current code you're compiling, "don't worry that you don't know anything about this class, I promise this class will exist at run time." You could even put "@class" ClassZ in any of your headers and have a property to it, but never create a file with the letter Z and the compiler would be fine with that.